# How to mark non-nullable a generic value-type cast?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, static-analysis

Let's say I have a generic function like the below one, which acts like a "switch" over the T-parameter type. My goal is to enforce the static analysis by adding some nullable check to the arguments.

```
    public static T? TryGet<T>(
        object instance,
        T fallback = default
        )
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) return (T)(object)TryGetAsInt32(instance, (int)(object)fallback);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(double)) return (T)(object)TryGetAsDouble(instance, (double)(object)fallback);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) return (T?)(object?)TryGetAsString(instance, (string?)(object?)fallback);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int?)) return (T)(object?)TryGetAsNullableInt32(instance, (int?)(object?)fallback);
        // many other cases...
        return fallback;
    }
```

As for example, the first inner callable function signature is something like this:

```
    public static int TryGetAsInt32(
        object instance,
        int fallback = default
        )
    {
        // ...
    }
```

As in the first snippet, both the `string` and the `int?` case seem correctly marked. However, both the `int` and the `double` are highlighted as warning due a "unboxing a possible null value". That's clearly not possible due the T type, which is a value-type.

```
TryGetAsInt32(instance, (int)(object)fallback);  //the object cast warns for a possible null
```

How to mark the cast as nullable-safe?

Comment: Not really sure what it is you're attempting to achieve in this method, but it seems very wrong to me. You shouldn't be writing type-based logic in generic methods. That defeats the entire purpose of generics.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I don't like it too, but there's no easy way to wrap all the common types in a single method. Anyway, I think you're right. It seems better to me to remove this pattern, and let the user call the single functions.

Comment: What's the use-case for this anyway? Why are you forced to deal with `object` to begin with?

Comment: well, that's part of a library, so I have no real use-cases. However, I agree that it has few sense having such a method. The cast to "object" is required because there's no implicit conversion between T and int. I may drop the sense of the function, but the original question remains unanswered.

Comment: `(int)(object)fallback!` [! (null-forgiving) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov at the very end! that's the only thing I didn't try! many thanks!

Comment: I know why you need the double casting, that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking why do you need to get an int from an object in the first place. What's the need for your `TryGet` method (or `TryGetAsInt32` for that matter)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled my suspect is about a template-like usage. We have records in a JSON, where each one is marked with its own type (numeric, string, etc). Probably it was an attempt to generalize the POCO describing them. I didn't find any case/reference in our sources right now.